# A Func object passed to a constructor ends up null

Tags: c#

I have a Singleton object, containing an anonymous delegate as property, and I want to give access to it to other classes in my program.

```
public sealed class HeuristicManager
{
    public Func<IMap, Owner, float> GetScore { get; protected set; }
    protected HeuristicDictionary weightedRules;

    private static readonly Lazy<HeuristicManager> lazy = new Lazy<HeuristicManager>(() => new HeuristicManager());
    public static HeuristicManager Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private HeuristicManager()
    {
        GetScore = (IMap map, Owner player) =>
        {
            float score = 0;
            foreach (var weightedRule in weightedRules)
                score += weightedRule.Key.EvaluateScore(map, player) + weightedRule.Value;
            return score / weightedRules.TotalWeight;
        };
    }
}
```

Some initalizations are missing but you get the idea. I'm using a Singleton instead of a static class because I want to store the previous results of my GetScore function for reuse.

I'm creating instances of an object somewhere else in my program that takes the GetScore function as a parameter, like this :

```
public override IEnumerable<TreeNode> ComputeNodeChildren()
{
    var mapPerNode = generateMapPerNode();
    foreach (var map in mapPerNode)
        yield return new TreeNode(map.Item1, map.Item2, HeuristicManager.Instance.GetScore);
}
```

My problem is that, when I call GetScore directly from the Singleton, it works perfectly, but once it's been passed to the TreeNode instance, it becomes null and my program crashes because i'm calling a null function.

The TreeNode constructor is below :

```
public TreeNode(IMap value, List<Move> moveList, Func<IMap, Owner, float> heuristic)
{
    Map = value;
    MoveList = moveList;
    this.heuristic = heuristic; // Both are null
    Heuristic = player => this.heuristic(Map, player); 
    ChildrenHashes = new List<int>();
}
```

I must be missing something, and I'd be glad to get some insights on this.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why the protected-set delegate?  A virtual method provides the same behavior, with much cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A minor optimization that might also solve your problem:  Lift the property access (which involves a custom getter, a `Lazy<T>` access, then an auto-prop) outside the loop:

```
public override IEnumerable<TreeNode> ComputeNodeChildren()
{
    var mapPerNode = generateMapPerNode();
    var scoreFn = HeuristicManager.Instance.GetScore;
    foreach (var map in mapPerNode)
        yield return new TreeNode(map.Item1, map.Item2, scoreFn);
}
```

Maybe even better

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> ComputeNodeChildrenImpl(TypeA mapPerNode, Func<IMap, Owner, float> scoreFn)
{
    foreach (var map in mapPerNode)
        yield return new TreeNode(map.Item1, map.Item2, scoreFn);
}

public override IEnumerable<TreeNode> ComputeNodeChildren()
{
    var mapPerNode = generateMapPerNode();
    var scoreFn = HeuristicManager.Instance.GetScore;
    return ComputeNodeChildrenImpl(mapPerNode, scoreFn);
}
```

Whenever a method contains `yield`, **all code in that method is executed lazily**.  Debugging and handling errors is generally much easier if argument validation and initialization are done eagerly, as shown.

Note that the second version can be written using LINQ's Select implementation as well, without an explicit helper:

```
public override IEnumerable<TreeNode> ComputeNodeChildren()
{
    var scoreFn = HeuristicManager.Instance.GetScore;
    return generateMapPerNode().Select(map => new TreeNode(map.Item1,
                                                           map.Item2, scoreFn));
}
```

Comment: @JabX: This version should be easier to single-step through... at what point does it become `null`?

Comment: In ComputeNodeChildren(), scoreFn() works as expected, but in the TreeNode constructor, called in .Select(), it is null.

Comment: You should be able to get a breakpoint on the lambda... or just go up the call stack when you break in the `TreeNode` constructor.  Actually, adding that call stack might be informative, in case something weird is going on with overloads.

Comment: Does the fact that this method runs in a Task (in a separate thread then) matter by the way? 
I tried doing it step by step, and it's still the same: the third argument of the TreeNode constructor is null whereas I can call the function in ComputeNodeChildren() with no problem.